# Problems installing laravel with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

**Problem:** I'm wanting to explore laravel 5, and failing miserably at installing it. I'm using this guide: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0 and need someone to help me understand the instructions.

**Background and What I've Tried**

I'm running Mac OSX 10.10.2 (Yosemite) and MAMP.

So far, I've downloaded Composer to my home folder using terminal. There is just a composer.phar file sitting there.

When I run:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

I get the message:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/MYUSERNAME/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

I assume that is ok because when I run the following in terminal, I get the composer logo and a list of options

```
~ MYUSERNAME$ composer
```

I'm not 100% sure what the following means, from the Laravel Docs:

```
"Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the 
laravel executable can be located by your system."
```

Because I can't figure it out, the following steps throw errors, such as:

```
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

I've been going through a few forums, and it's suggested that I need to update my PHP.ini file - this seems more related to Composer install, and not specifically Laravel. Because composer is working, this seems to be a dead end.

Ideally, I want to install Laravel 5 to the directory

```
HomeFolder/sites/test
```

because Composer.phar is in my home folder, I think the command should be:

```
php composer laravel new sites/test
```

or just

```
composer laravel new sites/test
```

As mentioned, it just (correctly) throws errors.

**Question:**
If anyone can help solve my total user error, by explaining what "Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system." means to a n00b, that'd be really appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Laravel is a PHP framework (makes writing PHP applications easy)

Composer is a PHP package and dependency manager. (makes installing and updating third party code libraries easy)

When you run

```
$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

You're using composer to install the `laravel/installer=~1.1` package into composer's "global" project folder (usually `~/.composer`).  This is what installed the command line program named `laravel`.

The command line program named `laravel` is a shell script for installing the PHP framework (Also named Laravel).

Your "Unix Path" is a list of folders where a command line script will search for an executable.  Usually is has folders like `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.  This is why when you run `ls`, you're actually running `/usr/bin/ls` -- the shell knows to check each folder in the path for a location.  You can view your current path by typing

```
$ echo $PATH
```

So, the problem is composer installed the `laravel` command line program to a folder that's not in your unix path.  You need to add this folder to your unix path.  You can do this by running the following (assuming you're using `bash`, which is OS X's default shell)

```
$ PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

If you run that, you should be able to run the `laravel` command line program and continue your installation.

Most people add this to their `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` files.  The [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) has a lot of good information if you're interested in learning how to do this.

Comment: really love the detailed answer, I used this in combination with the tutorial from @lukasgeiter answer and have it working. Thank you both for the explanation, and getting me up and running!

Comment: @alan-storm Is it recommended to leave the php composer vendor folder in the home directory where it is installed?

Comment: @MarkA I want to say yes, but I'm not sure what, exactly, you're asking.  "home directory" and vendor folder are a a little vague without context.  Sounds like you might want to ask a new question instead of commenting on an old one

Comment: @AlanStorm For example, npm puts all of the packages further up in the global directory. Would it be better to have composer moved to a global directory instead of the home directory?

Comment: @MarkA Still seems like you might want to ask a new question instead of commenting.

Comment: I struggled with the docs as-well, this did the trick.

Comment: Every framework that i have use before was so easy to install (2min)... first time with php and laravel, 5h later, no New Project :D

Comment: Even in 2017 you just saved my life, and every time again installing laravel takes me more time than developing the project itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the directory to the `PATH` variable by editing `/etc/paths`.
[Here's a tutorial on how to do that](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.VNKUimjF-1Z).

Just add a line with:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Then the `laravel new` command should work fine

---

If everything fails you can still use the `composer create-project` command to make a new laravel instance:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel sites/test --prefer-dist
```

Comment: The latter worked like a charm, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

I added C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin instead of ~/.composer/vendor/bin to the Path variable.

Here is instructions on changing the path variable on Windows 10:
http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path